# Restore IMEI of Xiaomi MI4C Without Another Phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, sim-card, imei, dual-sim

In short: I have a Xiaomi Mi4c that shows has an "unknown" IMEI when checked via the settings in the stable and developer versions of MIUI and Cyanogenmod 13.1. However, when viewed through EFS professional or NV RF Manager, the IMEI is read correctly. Not having a "valid" (or any?) IMEI means I have a 5" wifi tablet, rather than a phone, which is something I've been trying to fix.

The long version:

The problems started right after I flashed CM 13.1, and I couldn't detect my sim card. Thinking it was my ROM, I reflashed my stock ROM and when that didn't solve the problem, I quickly deduced that the missing/unknown IMEI was the problem.

I finally got NV RF Manager working, and read all of the NV values from my phone. After finding the IMEI related value, I followed the odd schema for rearranging my IMEI and filled the boxes out and clicked "Write NV." However, I only received an error that read "Parameter is write-protected and thus read only." The same results were achieved with EFS professional. (Again, this was on CM) Now, I reflashed the stock ROM, and tried again. After rebooting the phone, I was able to read the correct IMEI values from the phone using both EFS professinoal and NV RF Manager, but the phone still showed baseband and IMEI as "unknown." Dialing *#06# causes the numbers to disappear, but nothing else happens.

So far, this is what I've tried:

- NV RF Manager
- EFS Professional
- MTK Droid Tools
- SP Flash Tools (Did not work at all, only for MTK chipsets?)
- Apps like XPOSED IMEI Changer (Results in nothing changing)

There are a few related questions, but none of them work for me.

[How to restore IMEI and get back network functionality?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/how-to-restore-imei-and-get-back-network-functionality)

Might work, but I have been unable to find the "modem" or nvram files on my phone. I also don't have an "efs" folder on my phone (that I can find.)

[Mi4i full partition corrupted. Unable to restore EFS partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146531/mi4i-full-partition-corrupted-unable-to-restore-efs-partition)

Isn't jiving with me. The thought of uploading mi4i (rather than mi4c) specific files after removing my only remanents of my efs files seems like a bad idea to me.

[How to restore the IMEI number on the Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113667/how-to-restore-the-imei-number-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s4-i9505-imei-unknown-ba)

Is ROM specific, and since it doesn't work on multiple ROMs, I've ruled it out as related.

Again I have a Xiaomi Mi4C, the 32GB/3GB version with the Qualcomm MSM8992 Snapdragon 808 chipset.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I've hit a wall fixing this problem.

Comment: And there is issue number one: you have no efs folder. That is where your IMEI data is stored, along with all others sorts of ID (MAC address, BT address)

Comment: I thought this might be the problem, but I have a BT address, a MAC address and my wifi & BT connections are working just fine.

Comment: weird. That would all be efs, and devices tend to keep the system for that the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me. I've documented everything in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/biosafetylvl5/MI4C-IMEI-Restore), and have included some of the information here. However, I will not be updating this information, and I cannot upload the supporting files, making the GitHub repository the go to resource for many reasons. With that said, here is the excerpt:

### Download files

I've attached a few files:

1. **mi4c.qcn**: an IMEI backup from another phone
2. **QPST**: the program for uploading the IMEI backup
3. **IMEI converter** converts IMEI to hex

The IMEI converter is optional, but useful.

### Root phone and enable USB debugging

Other people have already written this part up, and in the spirit of refactoring, I will link to them rather than repeating what they say.

- Unlocking the Mi4c Bootloader without verification by Xiaomi
- Root and install twrp recovery on Xiaomi mi4c
- SuperSu install
- Enable USB debugging

### Setup other software

- Here's a guide for how to install ADB and Fastboot.
- You'll need a hex editor. Here's one, but there are many to choose from.

### Enable diagnostics mode

Open up your command prompt and run

```
adb shell
su
setprop sys.usb.config diag
```

This enables the diagnostics mode on your phone, priming it for QPST

### Check drivers

Go to "Device Manager" and check if your drivers are installed correctly. If they are not, try enabling unsigned drivers and reinstalling/updating the drivers for the phone.

### Edit mi4c.qcn

Open up your hex editor and search for "08 5A 44 13 66 06 75 76 36"
Change this to your IMEI that you converted into hex with the IMEI converter attached.

### Erase existing IMEI files

```
adb shell
su

dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p28 of=/sdcard/modemst1
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p29 of=/sdcard/modemst2
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p33 of=/sdcard/fsg

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p28
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p29
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p33

reboot
```

This clears the way for the new files.

### Repeat Enable diagnostics mode

### Use QPST to update EFS

Install and run QPST. It should automatically detect your phone.

Click the "Start Clients" tab, then select Software Download

Select your modified qcn file and click start. It may reach 100% quickly, but it will still be working until the exit button is not greyed out.

### Reboot phone

## Celebrate! (Or retry if not successful, sometimes it takes a few tries to get it right)

#### Credit to http://www.miuitutorial.com/2016/10/imei-xiaomi-mi4c-kamu-hilang-jangan.html and Defforest@enMiuiForum

Answer (score 1):

**What you need**.

- Download MTK Droid Root & tools.
- A Windows computer.
- Have already set USB Debugging mode enabled on your device.
- A USB cable.
- Have setup ADB & Fasboot on your PC.

**Instructions**.

1. Connect your device to PC, then launch MTK Droid Root & Tools.
2. Droid Root and Tools will detect your Android device.
3. If your device is detected, you will see its IMEI on the Phone Information tab on the droid root and tool interface.
4. Then find the Root button that's located on the lower right side of the interface.
5. Select Yes button if asked whether you wish to Root. You will see Root Shell Script Access.
6. Then you'll see a window box named Change IMEI, Backup/Restore, NVRAM.
7. Now replace the IMEI on the window box with the IMEI number from the rear side of your Android device.
8. Then choose Yes. Reboot your device for the changes to apply and finish.

I got the instructions from the following page; [repair MTK IMEI](https://www.androidflashtools.com/mtk-imei-repair-tool-mtkdroidtool/), that page contains pictures to clearer its point.

Comment: I'm afraid this method proved unsuccessful as well. Whilst it seems as if everything went smoothly, the IMEI is ultimately not restored.